# LINQ Enabling ADO.NET layer runs slower

Tags: c#, linq

I had some dataaccess code that I Linq enabled to raise the level of abstraction in the business layer but the performance is not excellent for large sets of data. Any Ideas on how to make it faster ?

```
public class StronglyTypedDataSource : IDisposable
{
    //
    private static readonly string _selectAll = "SELECT * FROM ";
    private static readonly string _insert = "INSERT INTO ";
    private static readonly string _update = "UPDATE ";
    private static readonly string _remove = "DELETE FROM ";
    private static readonly string _where = " WHERE ";
    private static readonly string _value = " VALUES ";
    private static readonly string _and = " AND ";
    private static readonly string _set = " SET ";
    private static readonly string _scopeIdentity = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
    private static string _connectionString;       
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private MySqlCommand command;
    private MySqlDataReader Reader;
    private int _indexer = 0;

    public StronglyTypedDataSource()
    {
        _connectionString = GetDefaultConnectionString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a record from a database table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="predicate"></param>
    /// <param name="optionalTableName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T Read<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string optionalTableName = null) where T : class
    {

        T returnValue = default(T);
        CreateReadCommand<T>(predicate, optionalTableName);
        var holder = GetDataRows<T>(1).ToList();
        if(holder != default(T) && holder.Any())
            returnValue = holder[0];
        connection.Close();
        return returnValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a sequence of records from a database table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="optionalTableName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> ReadAll<T>(string optionalTableName = null) where T : class
    {
        return ReadAll<T>(null, optionalTableName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a sequence of records from a database table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="predicate"></param>
    /// <param name="optionalTableName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> ReadAll<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string optionalTableName = null) where T : class
    {          
        CreateReadCommand<T>(predicate, optionalTableName);
        var returnValues = GetDataRows<T>().ToList();
        connection.Close();
        return returnValues;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete records fromt a database table that matches the predicate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="predicate"></param>
    /// <param name="optionalTableName"></param>
    public void Delete<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string optionalTableName = null) where T : class
    {
        CreateReadCommand<T>(predicate, optionalTableName, false);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts a record into a database table.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectToSave"></param>
    /// <param name="optionalTableName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public int Save<T>(T objectToSave, string optionalTableName = null, bool update = false, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null) where T : class
    {
        if (!update)
            return InsertTableRow<T>(objectToSave, optionalTableName);
        else if (predicate != null)
            return UpdateTableRow<T>(objectToSave, predicate, optionalTableName);
        else
            return -1;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// executes the specified by passing using the dictionary of parameters supplied.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="storedProcName"></param>
    /// <param name="optionalValues"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteStoredProcdure<T>(string storedProcName, Dictionary<string, object> optionalValues) where T : class
    {          
        InitializeQueryEngine();
        command.CommandText = storedProcName;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        optionalValues = optionalValues ?? new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var optionalValuesEnumerator = optionalValues.GetEnumerator();
        while (optionalValuesEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(optionalValuesEnumerator.Current.Key, optionalValuesEnumerator.Current.Value);
        }
        return GetDataRows<T>();

    }

    private void InitializeQueryEngine()
    {
        connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
        command = connection.CreateCommand(); 
        if(connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)       
            connection.Open();
        _indexer = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Parses the expression tree.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="predicate"></param>
    /// <param name="optionalTableName"></param>
    /// <param name="isSelect"></param>
    protected internal void CreateReadCommand<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string optionalTableName = null, bool isSelect = true)
    {          

        InitializeQueryEngine();
        string parametizedCommandString = String.Empty;
        string whereClause = predicate != null ? AnalyzePredicate(predicate) : String.Empty;          

        parametizedCommandString = ((isSelect ? _selectAll : _remove) + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(optionalTableName) ? typeof(T).Name : optionalTableName) + (whereClause ?? string.Empty));

        command.CommandText = parametizedCommandString;            
    }
    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToExpression<T>(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, new ParameterExpression[]{ Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)) });
    }
    private string AnalyzePredicate<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, bool isFirstParse = true)
    {
        string whereClause = String.Empty;
        BinaryExpression expression = (BinaryExpression)predicate.Body;
        if (!(expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal || expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso))
            throw new NotSupportedException("Only == and && operator is supported");           

        if (expression.Left is BinaryExpression)
        {
            var leftExpression = (BinaryExpression)expression.Left;              
            whereClause += AnalyzePredicate<T>(ToExpression<T>((BinaryExpression)expression.Left), _indexer == 0);             
        }            

        if (expression.Right is BinaryExpression)
        {
            var rightExpression = (BinaryExpression)expression.Right;
            whereClause += AnalyzePredicate<T>(ToExpression<T>((BinaryExpression)expression.Right), _indexer == 0);
        }

        if (expression.Left is MemberExpression)
        {
            whereClause += ConvertExpressionToSQL<T>(expression, isFirstParse);
            _indexer++;
        }

        return whereClause;
    }

    private string ConvertExpressionToSQL<T>(BinaryExpression expression, bool isFirstParse)
    {
        string whereClause = String.Empty;
        if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal)
        {
            var parsedExpression = GetLeftRightExpresion(expression);
            whereClause += (isFirstParse ? _where : _and) + parsedExpression.Item1.Member.Name + "= " + "@" + parsedExpression.Item1.Member.Name;
            if (command.Parameters != null && !command.Parameters.Contains("@" + parsedExpression.Item1.Member.Name))
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + parsedExpression.Item1.Member.Name, parsedExpression.Item2);
        }

        return whereClause;
    }

    private Tuple<MemberExpression, object> GetLeftRightExpresion(BinaryExpression expression)
    {
        object value = null;
        if (expression.Right is ConstantExpression)
            value = ((ConstantExpression)expression.Right).Value;
        else
            value = Expression.Lambda(expression.Right).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
        return new Tuple<MemberExpression, object>((MemberExpression)expression.Left, value);


    }

    protected internal IEnumerable<T> GetDataRows<T>(int maxRows = -1) where T : class
    {         
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int number_of_returned_rows = 0;
        List<T> resrtul = new List<T>();
        if (Reader.HasRows)
        {
            var returnValueProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
            var returnValuePropertiesEnumerator = returnValueProperties.GetEnumerator();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                if (maxRows != -1 && number_of_returned_rows >= maxRows)
                    break;
                T returnValue = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
                while (returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    var currentProperty = (PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current;
                    if (Attribute.IsDefined(currentProperty, typeof(GCHDBIgnoreAttribute)))
                        continue;
                    if (Reader[currentProperty.Name].GetType().FullName == "MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime")
                        currentProperty.SetValue(returnValue, DateTime.Parse(Reader[currentProperty.Name].ToString()), null);
                    else if (Reader[currentProperty.Name].GetType().FullName == "System.DBNull")
                        continue;
                    else
                        currentProperty.SetValue(returnValue, Reader[currentProperty.Name], null);
                }
                number_of_returned_rows++;                    
                yield return returnValue;
                returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Reset();
            } 
         }
        else
            yield return default(T);
    }

    protected internal int InsertTableRow<T>(T row, string optionalTableName = null)
    {

        var returnValueProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var returnValuePropertiesEnumerator = returnValueProperties.GetEnumerator();
        StringBuilder parametizedCommandString = new StringBuilder(_insert + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(optionalTableName) ? row.GetType().Name : optionalTableName) + "( ");
        var placeHolders = new List<string>();

        InitializeQueryEngine();

        while (returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (Attribute.IsDefined((PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current, typeof(GCHDBIgnoreAttribute)))
                continue;
            var currentPropertyName = ((PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current).Name;
            parametizedCommandString.Append(currentPropertyName);
            parametizedCommandString.Append(", ");
            placeHolders.Add("@" + currentPropertyName);
        }
        parametizedCommandString.Remove(parametizedCommandString.Length - 2, 1);           
        parametizedCommandString.Append(" )" + _value + "( ");

        for (int i = 0; i < placeHolders.Count; i++)
        {
            parametizedCommandString.Append(placeHolders[i]);
            parametizedCommandString.Append(", ");
        }
        parametizedCommandString.Remove(parametizedCommandString.Length - 2, 1);
        parametizedCommandString.Append(" )");
        returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Reset();
        for (int i = 0; i < placeHolders.Count; i++)
        {                
            returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.MoveNext();
            if (Attribute.IsDefined((PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current, typeof(GCHDBIgnoreAttribute)))
                continue;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue(placeHolders[i], ((PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current).GetValue(row, null));
        }
        command.CommandText = parametizedCommandString.ToString();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.CommandText = _scopeIdentity;
        return Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

    }

    protected internal int UpdateTableRow<T>(T row, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, string optionalTableName)
    {
        var returnValueProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        var returnValuePropertiesEnumerator = returnValueProperties.GetEnumerator();
        StringBuilder parametizedCommandString = new StringBuilder(_update + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(optionalTableName) ? row.GetType().Name : optionalTableName) + _set);
        var placeHolders = new List<string>();

        InitializeQueryEngine();

        while (returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (Attribute.IsDefined((PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current, typeof(GCHDBIgnoreAttribute)))
                continue;
            var currentPropertyName = ((PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current).Name;
            parametizedCommandString.Append(currentPropertyName + "= @" + currentPropertyName);
            parametizedCommandString.Append(", ");
            placeHolders.Add("@" + currentPropertyName);
        }
        parametizedCommandString.Remove(parametizedCommandString.Length - 2, 1);            
        parametizedCommandString.Append(AnalyzePredicate<T>(predicate));
        returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Reset();
        for (int i = 0; i < placeHolders.Count; i++)
        {
            returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.MoveNext();
            if (Attribute.IsDefined((PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current, typeof(GCHDBIgnoreAttribute)))
                continue;
            if(command.Parameters != null && !command.Parameters.Contains(placeHolders[i]))
             command.Parameters.AddWithValue(placeHolders[i], ((PropertyInfo)returnValuePropertiesEnumerator.Current).GetValue(row, null));

        }
        command.CommandText = parametizedCommandString.ToString();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Parameters.Clear();

        return 0;
    }

    protected internal string GetDefaultConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TSIF_DefaultConnectionString"].ConnectionString;             
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (connection != null && connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Dispose();               
        }
    }

    ~StronglyTypedDataSource()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you expect people to _read_ all that code? And what have _you_ tried as far as making it faster, or at least, figuring out where it's slow?

Comment: Why don't you use a profiler on the code?

Comment: Help help! I invented a square wheel and it doesn't work like I want on roads, help me fix it so I don't need to go out and use any of the hundreds of round wheels that I could get off the shelf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection in a tight loop will always be slow. `GetDataRows` is obviously the source of your bottleneck.

```
var returnValueProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
var returnValuePropertiesEnumerator = returnValueProperties.GetEnumerator();
```

The above lines are going to be seriously slow, yet you tight loop them.

Then you go even worse by using `PropertyInfo.SetValue`.

Its obvious you have some skill in Linq Expresssions. So you should replace that ENTIRE function with a Linq Expression which you compile to a delegate, AND more crucially, YOU SHOULD CACHE THE RESULTS OF YOUR LINQ COMPILE.

Consider using a static helper class, with a static constructor to initialize your mapping delegate.

However. This does not fix the more fundamental problem that you are reinventing the wheel. You could have just used a library such as [DbExecuter](http://dbexecutor.codeplex.com/) for your reader logic. Heck, you could have easily just used EntityFramework or Linq to SQL.

Comment: Linq-to-SQL does not support MySQL (that OP is using).

Comment: @Gabe [Devart Linq Connect](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/) and if you are going to say "its expensive", then you have obviously never tried to write and support your own library. I would have accepted that MySQL doesn't support EF, since I've looked at their source code and its complete crap. But that's just Oracle for you. Protip, use MariaDB, its a branch of MySQL that isn't actively being sabotaged by one of the largest RBDMS vendors in the world